# A Question Raised about Strong Cayley Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory

In the beginning steps of [Strong Cayley theorem](https://math.la.asu.edu/~kawski/classes/mat444/handouts/strongCayley.pdf), I got stuck at a point.

> $H\leqslant G,\,\Sigma=\{Hx\mid x\in G\}$, we define
>   \begin{align*}
> P~:~G&\longrightarrow S(\Sigma),\\g&\longmapsto Hxg.
> \end{align*}
>   The permutation representation is such: 
>   \begin{gather*}
> P(g)=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
> Hx_1&Hx_2&\cdots&Hx_n\\
> Hx_1g&Hx_2g&\cdots&Hx_ng
> \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> Hx_ig
> \end{array}\right).
> \end{gather*}
>   It's easy to show $P$ is a homomorphism：
>   \begin{gather*}
> P(a)\circ P(b)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> Hx_ia
> \end{array}\right)\circ\left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> Hx_ib
> \end{array}\right)~,\forall a,b\in G.
> \end{gather*}
>   This shows that $P$ changes $Hx_i$ into $Hx_ib$ firstly, then $Hx_i$ into $Hx_ia$:
>   \begin{gather*}
> P(a)\circ P(b)=P(a)\circ \left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> Hx_ib
> \end{array}\right)
> =\left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> (Hx_ia)b
> \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{l}
> Hx_i\\
> Hx_i(ab)
> \end{array}\right)=P(ab).
> \end{gather*}

However, when I employ the right induced representation :
We set $\Omega=\{xH\mid x\in G\},$
\begin{align*}
O~:~G&\longrightarrow S(\Omega),\\g&\longmapsto gxH,
\end{align*}
I can't find the way to show that $O$ is still a homomorphism.

Is there anything that I miss or understood? Any help is sincerely appreciated.

> **PS**: When we apply the same logic in the map O as P, we’ll get: $$(O(a)O(b))(xH)= O(a)(O(b)(xH)) =(Hxb)a=Hx(ba)=O(ba),$$which is ridiculous considering the acknowledged fact that $O(ab)=O(a)\circ O(b)$. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the map $O$ sends $g\in G$ to the permutation on $\Omega$ defined by $O(g)(xH)=gxH$, for $xH\in\Omega$. Then for $g,h\in G$, and arbitrary $xH\in\Omega$,
$$
O(gh)(xH)=ghxH=O(g)(hxH)=O(g)O(h)(xH),
$$
so that $O(gh)=O(g)O(h)$ as permutations on $\Omega$.

Comment: When we apply the same logic in the map P, we’ll get: $P(ab)(Hx)=(Hxa)b=P(b)\circ (Hxa)=P(b)\circ P(a)$, considering that $P(ab)=P(a)\circ P(b)$, it will be ridiculous. Why?

Comment: @Benny The second equality in the last line of your quoted block is incorrect, since $P(a)(Hx_ib)=Hx_iba)$. Right multiplication in this case is an antihomomorphism, $P(ab)=P(b)P(a)$. You can make a homomorphism by defining instead $P(a)(Hx)=Hxa^{-1}$.

Comment: I should add there's not really any content to the discrepancies between what is a homomorphism and antihomomorphism here, it's mostly due to the convention of writing function composition on the left.

Comment: Thank you. But I do not quite understand what you mean by “convention of writing function composition”, as which was the same answer from teacher.

Comment: @Benny If you write function composition on the right, say $(Hx)P(a)=Hxa$, you'll find that right multiplication is a homomorphism, but left multiplication $(xH)O(a)=axH$ is now an antihom.

Comment: That is surprising to me! Thanks!